# Python- Bar chart real time

Tags: javascript, python, animation, real-time, bar-chart

How can I create a bar/column chart in python using animation in real time ? I have made static bar graphs. Currently I have a program that feeds value from a machine to an excel file and my program should read that file in real time and plot a bar graph. I just want to look at patterns. It should update after every 100 points. Thanks in advance !For more clarification I would like to add that it should look like the bar graph in the video provided in the link https://www.pond5.com/stock-footage/58163733/animated-line-bar-charts-business-plan-presentation-showing.html 
but should not be a image and should update real time data. 
I am okay if I can do this in Javascript as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like matplotlib.animation might meet your needs.

Docs: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/

Tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/python-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs/

Comment: I have looked over the documentation and have already produced a line graph but unfortunately I need a column graph that can update itself. I tried to just replace it but it did not work. It would be really helpful if you could provide an example. Really sorry as I am new to Python I cannot get the solution you posted. Thanks